# UISplitViewController return from master to detail

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible on iPhone via `UISplitViewController` to return from the master controller to the detail one? I have tried in master changing `displayMode` to `PrimaryHidden`, using `showDetailViewController` with `splitViewController?.viewControllers[0]`, but nothing was able to show back the detail controller.

I would like to have both controllers without dismissing and reloading, because one includes a map and the second one preferences of map objects.

Comment: the question is not clear, are you asking if you can have the full split view on an iPhone like it is on iPads?

Comment: No, i just want to go from master to detail. I click the bar button arrow to go to master but i dont know how to go back to detail.

Comment: well, thats kinda your job to create something that will let you segue to split view. It can be button or any control which you can perform segue

Comment: I'll give you an example

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a button in the master view which when pressed will take you to detail view. Here is an example how that would go

```
@IBAction func buttonToGoToDetailView(sender: UIButton) {
     performSegueWithIdentifier("segue id in storyboard", sender: nil)
}
// prpare for segua to detail view
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
     let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? UIViewController
     if let dvc = destination as? NameOfTheDetailViewController{
            if segue.identifier = "segue id in storyboard" {
                //use dvc to pass data to the detail if there is any    
            }
     }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this, but the detail controller is reloaded. I need to pull the old detail controller from the stack. Not load a new one.